# Understanding why it does not find duplicates in array

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote the following function in C:

```
int last(long arr[], int length) {
   for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
       if (*(arr+i) == *(arr + length - 1)) 
           return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

it checks if the last value of the array was used more than once. In the main:

```
int *arr = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
   scanf("%d", ++arr);
printf(last((long *) arr, length);
```

For some reason for the array `[1,2,2,3]` it returns that the last element was used multiple times and I'm not sure why. I think that is because of `scanf("%d", ++arr);` but I don't know how to fix it.
My goal is that it will return `1` for `[1,3,2,3]` and `0` for `[1,2,2,3]`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Using the debugger to step through the code should show you why it's not working as expected. Have you tried stepping through the code in `last()`? It should be very easy with an array that only contains 4 items.

Comment: I tried the debugger and I understand the issue, I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I want to compare all elements with the last one and just with the last one

Comment: @JL2210 I think it comes from `scanf("%d", ++arr);`. I tried to print that array and It prints garbage values.

Comment: `printf(last((long *) arr, length);`: `last` returns an `int`. I sense that you didn't try this beforehand. Perhaps read [mcve]?

Comment: @vesii Yes, correct. You're incrementing the array before you pass it to `last`. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `scanf("%d", &arr[i]);`. Using `++arr` causes the array to be incremented before you pass it to `last`, and also reads into data beyond `arr`, which is undefined behavior.

Another one of the issues in this is the cast to `long *`.

You should use `%ld` in `scanf` and `long *arr = malloc(length*sizeof(*arr));`.

Also make sure to check for `NULL`. You never know when `malloc` is going to fail or someone's going to pass bad data.

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int last(long arr[], int length) {
   if(!arr) return -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
   {
       if (arr[i] == arr[length-1])
           return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    long *arr = malloc(4*sizeof(*arr));
    if(!arr) return 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        scanf("%ld", &arr[i]);
    printf("%d\n", last(arr, 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several problems in your code:

Look at this statement:

```
scanf("%d", ++arr);
            ^^^^^
```

In the last iteration of loop, the pointer `arr` will be pointing to one element past end of array `arr` (due to pre-increment) and it is is passed to `scanf()`. The `scanf()` will access the memory location pointed by the pointer which is an invalid memory because your program does not own it. This is *undefined behavior*. **Note that a pointer may point to one element past the end of array, this is as per standard but dereferencing such pointer will lead to undefined behavior**.

Once the `main()` function `for` loop finishes the `arr` pointer pointing to  location past the end of memory allocated to `arr` and just after this you are passing `arr` to `last()` function. So, you are passing an invalid memory reference to `last()` function and then accessing that memory in `last()` function - one more *undefined behavior* in your program.

Probably you should take another pointer and point it to `arr`, so that `arr` keep pointing to allcoated memory reference returned by `malloc()`.
Note that if you want to read the input the way you are doing then use the post-increment operator in `scanf()`, like this:

```
int *arr = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
if (arr == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

int *ptr = arr;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    scanf("%d", ptr++);
```

but the more appropriate and readable way is - `scanf("%d", &arr[i])`.

Another big problem in your code is accessing the `int` values as `long` type.
The `last()` function parameter `arr` type is `long` and you are passing it `int` pointer typecasted to `long *`.
Note that the size of `long` and `int` may be **different** based on the platform. You cannot assume them to be of same size on all platforms.
Assume the case where `int` size is `4` bytes and `long` size is `8` bytes.
In this case, when accessing an `int` pointer using `long` type pointer then every object will be considered as `8` byte long and when you do `arr+1` in `last()`, the pointer will be advance by `8` bytes and you will never get correct result.

Compiler must be throwing warning message on this statement:

```
printf(last((long *) arr, length);
```

because the `printf()` expects first argument as `const char *` and you are passing it `int` (return type of `last()`). You should give the first argument to `printf()` a string which contains appropriate format specifier('s).

Putting these altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int last(int arr[], int length) {
   if (arr == NULL) {
       return 1;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
       if (arr[i] == arr[length - 1]) {
           return 1;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    int length = 4;
    int *arr = malloc (length * sizeof (*arr));

    if (arr == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf ("Enter %d numbers:\n", length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  {
        scanf ("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf ("Duplicate found: %s\n", last (arr, length) == 1 ? "Yes" : "No");

    return 0;
}
```